# spring state machine reset

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I have a question about reset state machine. 
configuration

```
protected StateMachine<ProfilingState, ProfilingEvent> buildStateMachine(
            StateMachineBuilder.Builder<SomeState, SomeEvent> builder) throws Exception {

  builder.configureStates()
                .withStates()
                .initial(SomeState.State1)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(SomeState.class));

        builder.configureTransitions()
                .withExternal()
                .source(SomeState.Step1)
                .target(SomeState.Step2)
                .event(SomeEvent.Event1)
                .action(step1Action())
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(SomeState.Step2)
                .target(SomeState.Step3)
                .event(SomeEvent.Event2)
                .action(step2Action())
                .and();
            return builder.build();
        }
```

I have api for persisting/restoring state machine. During restoring I make reset state machine to previous persisted state.

```
stateMachine
    .getStateMachineAccessor()
    .doWithAllRegions(access -> {
        access.resetStateMachine(
            new DefaultStateMachineContext(currentState, null, null, extendedState));
});
stateMachine.start();
```

I expect that I can reset state machine after jvm crash and continue from my last persisted state. 
For instance last persisted state is Step2. Let's assume that action for Step2 is a long loop. Let's suppose that Jvm crash was occurred some were in the middle of processing this loop. During application startup the application recognizes that there are unfinished flows. 
So the goal is to continue from last persisted state. This mean that after reset state machine to State2 I expect that the step2Action will be triggered and I will continue processing, because Step2 wasn't finished.
Unfortunately, after I reset state machine to State2 the step2Action wasn't invoked.
Is it possible to trigger this action for this case?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not as `step2Action` action is attached to a transition and reset doesn't cause any entry for a state.

Feel free to create enhancement request on github as when thinking about what might happen after a reset, a state action might be executed. We would never execute an entry action as state is not entered during a reset but as I said, it might make sense to execute state do action.